# Android CTS test can run on multiple devices in parallel

Tags: android, cts

Android CTS documents said as below.

"To shard a plan test run on multiple devices:-

```
run cts -plan CTS --shards <number of shards>
```

then I do in this way. but I can not do.
surely PC can recognize the multi devices but cannot run on them.

If you know how, please help me!!!

---

I'm sorry. the above comment was not drawn in details.

I show you what I did.

Firstly I downloaded Android 4.0.3 R3 Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)
from the following google site.
 http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html

then I constructed CTS and SDK in my PC
and connected 2 device to my PC.

I executed the commands as below.

1. ./android-cts/tool/cts-tradefed
2. run -plan CTS --shards 2

Consequently, the following message was shown.

cts-tf>10-23 18:xx:xx I/unknown_devices:
 Created result dir 2012.10.xx._xx.xx.xx
 Android CTS 4.0.3_r3
 I/Device Manager : Detected new device a61xxxxx
 I/Device Manager : Detected new device de0xxxxx

but after that, no message was shown.

Comment: Can you add more details? Is there any error message that can help answering the question? Any details that you can add will help you get an answer faster.

Comment: Thank you for comment. If it is hard to understand, Please tell me!

Answer (score 5):

You won't see test status output on the console when sharding. You can use the '-l debug' option to 'run cts' to see debug information.

For example:

```
run cts --plan CTS --shards 2 -l debug
```

If you input the above command in console, you can see all the activities going on your 2 devices. Like installing the testrunner apks, running the tests and uninstalling the apks after tests.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate you. I examined option '-l debug'. then I can see the log, the parallel test succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the device id's of the connected devices.

Command to get the device ID : `adb devices`

Update device ID and run the below command:

`run -plan CTS --shards 2 --serial <device id1> --serial <device id2>`